# Django unable to access admin login page after creating superuser

Tags: django, python-3.x, admin

i am a new python Django learner for the first time
i have a problem with access and login admin after creating superuser account

python version : 3.7.0
Django version : 3.0.4

below is models.py and i migrated with it. checked my db with sqlite3 which has no problem

```
class Fcuser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='username')

    password = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='passward')


    registed_dttm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True, verbose_name='regstedtime')
```

this is the urls.py never changed anything

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

after that, i created a superuser which is successfully done.

i started the server with "python manage.py runserver"
and access to 127.0.0.1:8000

it is possible to access to access 127.0.0.1:8000

but the problem is...

when i try to access to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

there are 3 cases showed up

1. cannot access to the admin page without any error msg.
   it seems it is automatically shutdown the server.
2. can access to the admin page sometimes but after trying to login with superuser account, it automatically shutdown the server without any error msg again
3. trying to access again with other browser, able to access admin page first but cannot login with the superuser account again, also shows no error msg and shutdown the server again

this shows all of the terminal status

> ```
> *(Django_og) C:\django_basic\fc_community>python manage.py runserver
> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
> March 11, 2020 - 03:15:29
> Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'fc_community.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> (Django_og) C:\django_basic\fc_community>*
> ```

*

with this problem... cannot even get to the next step...

hope you guys would help this python Django beginner :(

Comment: Did you create your superuser with 'python manage.py createsuperuser'? Also are you sure that there's only one server running that is listening to port 8000?

Comment: yes i did with 'python manage.py createsuperuser'(Django_og) 
 "C:\django_basic\fc_community>python manage.py createsuperuser"
i see "Superuser created successfully." also there is only one server listening to port 8000, i checked in CMD with netsata -ano commend